# Mobile web design HTML ul affecting image below it when rotating device

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-lists

Hi I am having issues with my website. It runs fine on computers but on mobile devices the price table I am using is affecting the image below it. The price table is within a ul class when I look at the picture below it portrait then switch to landscape the image disappears. If I taken out all the price tables the image will rotate on mobiles and not disappear. So I know that the ul class is affecting the image but I dont know how to fix it.

```
    <ul class="pricing_table">

            <li class="price_block">
            <h3><h3>Mini Facial </h3></h3>

            <div class="price">
                <div class="price_figure">
                    <span class="price_number">&pound; 15</span>
                    <span class="price_tenure">30 minutes</span>
                    <span class="price_tenure">All Skin Types</span>

                </div>
            </div>  

        </li>

        <li class="price_block">
            <h3><h3>Facial</h3></h3>

            <div class="price">
                <div class="price_figure">
                    <span class="price_number">&pound; 24</span>
                    <span class="price_tenure">1 Hour</span>
                    <span class="price_tenure">All Skin Types</span>

                </div>
            </div>  
        </li>

        <li class="price_block">
            <h3><h3>Back Facial</h3></h3>

            <div class="price">
                <div class="price_figure">
                    <span class="price_number">&pound; 26</span>
                        <span class="price_tenure">30 minutes</span>
                        <span class="price_tenure">All Skin Types</span>
                </div>
            </div>  

        </li>


</ul>

    <a name="barbering"></a>
                        <section class="photo5" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
                    </section>
```

css

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu);

    * {
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0px;
    }

    body {
        font-family: Ubuntu, arial, verdana;

    }

    .pricing_table {
        line-height: 150%; 
        font-size: 12px; 
        margin: 1px auto; 
        width: 75%; 
        max-width: 800px; 
        padding-top: 10px;
        margin-top: 50px;

    }

    .price_block {
        width: 100%; 
        color: #8bbab4; 
        float: left; 
        list-style-type: none; 
        transition: all 0.25s; 
        position: relative; 
        box-sizing: border-box;

        margin-bottom: 10px; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; 
    }

    .pricing_table h3 {
        text-transform: uppercase; 
        padding: 5px 0; 
        background: #FFFFFF; 
        margin: -10px 0 1px 0;
    }

    .price {
        display: table; 
        background: #FFFFFF; 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 70px; 
    }
    .price_figure {
        font-size: 24px; 
        text-transform: uppercase; 
        vertical-align: middle; 
        display: table-cell;
    }
    .price_number {
        font-weight: bold; 
        display: block;
    }
    .price_tenure {
        font-size: 11px; 
    }

    .features {
        background: #8bbab4; 
        color: #8bbab4;
    }
    .features li {
        padding: 8px 15px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #8bbab4; 
        font-size: 11px; 
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .footer {
        padding: 15px; 
        background: #8bbab4;
    }
    .action_button {
        text-decoration: none; 
        color: #8bbab4; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        border-radius: 5px; 
        background: linear-gradient(#8bbab4, #8bbab4); 
        padding: 5px 20px; 
        font-size: 11px; 
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .price_block:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
        transform: scale(1.04) translateY(-5px); 
        z-index: 1; 
        border-bottom: 0 none;
    }
    .price_block:hover .price {
        background:linear-gradient(#8bbab4, #8bbab4); 
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 45px 1px #FFFFFF;
    }
    .price_block:hover h3 {
        background: #222;
    }
    .price_block:hover .action_button {
        background: linear-gradient(#8bbab4, #8bbab4); 
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) and (max-width : 768px) {
        .price_block {width: 50%;}
        .price_block:nth-child(odd) {border-right: 1px solid transparent;}
        .price_block:nth-child(3) {clear: both;}

        .price_block:nth-child(odd):hover {border: 0 none;}
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 768px){
        .price_block {width: 25%;}
        .price_block {border-right: 1px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0 none;}
        .price_block:last-child {border-right: 0 none;}

        .price_block:hover {border: 0 none;}
    }

.photo5{
background: url(barbering.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    top: 48px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a link to your version? I've run your code locally and checked on dev tools. Picture is still there when I change position of emulated device.

Comment: http://polishedsunderland.com/ its up and running on this site as you can see on mobiles turning it from portrait to horizontal the images disappears here is a link to the drop box rar file of the site https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62302481/polished%20website%20-%20Copy.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ul fault, it's parallax plugin. When you scroll down on portrait view it change background position to some value using javascript. Then you rotate your device to landscape and value that was set up by plugin is still the same even if distance form the top of the page to your container with picture has changed.

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: thank you really appreciate your insight, Im not very good at web design Im just doing this as a favor for a relative. I would have never worked that out. I guess I'll change the parallax scrolling affect because I have no idea how to fix the java.  I would up vote you but I dont have enough rep yet. thank you a lot.

Comment: No worries, you can always up vote later, when you get more ;) I'm glad I could help you.